# Dynamics of a discrete stochastic classical model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, partition-function

I was going through Dijkgraaf (https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1927) and I came across the following two equations

1. $$
   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \tau} P_{\alpha}(\tau)=\sum_{\substack{\beta \\ \beta \neq \alpha}}\left(W_{\alpha \beta} P_{\beta}(\tau)-W_{\beta \alpha} P_{\alpha}(\tau)\right),
   $$
2. $$
   W_{\beta \alpha} P_{\alpha}^{(0)}=W_{\alpha \beta} P_{\beta}^{(0)}
   $$

$W_{\beta \alpha}$ is the transition rate from state $\alpha$ to $\beta$, and $\tau$ is the time. $P_{\alpha}(\tau)$ is the probability of the system to be in configuration $\alpha$ at time $\tau$.

The first is the master equation for a discrete stochastic classical model and the second is the expression for a detail balance condition.

Could anyone explain how 1. is derived and why 2. gives the detail balance condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the derivation, a disclaimer. The equation (1) (hereby referred to as the master equation) is only valid for markovian processes. In a nutshell, Markovian processes are processes where the probability of something happening depends only on the previous step. In terms of probabilities, this means

$$ P(\alpha(t_n)| \alpha(t_{n-1}), ..., \alpha(t_1)) = P(\alpha(t_n)| \alpha(t_{n-1}))$$

This is why they are sometimes called memoryless processes. Furthermore, it turns out these processes satisfy a crucial property (which we will use to derive the master equation) called Chapman-Kolmogorov equation:

$$ P(\alpha, t_1|\beta,t_3) = \sum_{\gamma}P(\alpha, t_1|\gamma,t_2) P(\gamma, t_2|\beta,t_3) \tag{1}$$

where we sum over all the intermediate states $\gamma$. Fun fact, this is the exact property satisfied by the Feynman Propagator and the starting point to derive path integrals in Quantum Mechanics. Now, we shall use equation (1) to derive the master equation. But before, consider

$$ P(\alpha, t+ \delta t|\beta, t) = P(\alpha, t|\beta, t) + \left . \frac{\partial P(\alpha,t'| \beta,t)}{\partial t'} \right  \rvert_{t'= t} \delta t + ...  = \delta_{\alpha \beta} + W_{\alpha \beta} \delta t + \mathcal{O}(\delta t^2)$$

where we have used the fact that the states $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are exclusive so $P(\alpha, t|\beta, t) = \delta_{\alpha \beta}$ and identified $\left . \frac{\partial P(\alpha,t'| \beta,t)}{\partial t'} \right  \rvert_{t'= t} = W_{\alpha \beta}$ as the transition rate. This depends on the model you consider. Finally, because $\sum_\alpha P(\alpha, t) = 1$ at any time,

$$ \sum_\alpha P(\alpha, t+ \delta t|\beta, t) = 1 = \sum_\alpha \left (\delta _{\alpha \beta} + W_{\alpha \beta} \delta t\right) = 1 + \sum_\alpha W_{\alpha \beta} \delta t$$

This immediately implies that $\sum_\alpha W_{\alpha \beta} = 0$ and that $$ W_{\beta \beta} = -\sum_{\alpha \neq \beta} W_{\alpha \beta} \tag{2}$$

We are now ready to derive the master equation. In equation (1), replace $t_1 = t+\delta t$, $t_2 = t$ and $t_3 = t'$:

$$ P(\alpha, t+\delta t|\beta,t') = \sum_{\gamma}P(\alpha, t+\delta t|\gamma,t) P(\gamma, t|\beta,t')$$

Now expanding in $\delta t$ both sides and matching terms of $\delta t$, we have

$$ \frac{\partial P_\alpha}{\partial t} = \sum_{\gamma} W_{\alpha \gamma} P_\gamma = \sum_{\gamma \neq \alpha} (W_{\alpha \gamma} P_\gamma) + W_{\alpha \alpha} P_\alpha$$

Using equation (2), we have our final result

$$ \frac{\partial P_\alpha}{\partial t} = \sum_{\gamma \neq \alpha} (W_{\alpha \gamma} P_\gamma - W_{\gamma \alpha} P_\alpha )$$

This completes the derivation. Now, consider the steady state solution where $\partial_t P_\alpha = 0 $. The master equation implies

$$ \sum_{\gamma \neq \alpha} (W_{\alpha \gamma} P_\gamma - W_{\gamma \alpha} P_\alpha ) = 0$$

One solution is $W_{\alpha \gamma} P_\gamma = W_{\gamma \alpha} P_\alpha$. This is called the detailed balance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was the answer I was looking for!